# Swap Activity Order

Tags: android, xml, android-activity

This is a very basic doubt. I have a MainActivity, and I created another Activity that is supposed to act as an transparent screen to the MainActivity. Thus, I want this 2nd Activity, say DisplayHelpActivity, to be shown first, when the app starts. Is the only way to change is to swap names and code, or is there another way to specify the order in which the activities should occur? Please help me. By the way, when the DisplayHelpActivity Transparent screen is on, I want the MainActivity to be shown in the background.

Comment: Just have your MainActivity as your MAIN/LAUNCHER activity in the manifest and get it to immediately start your transparent help activity.

Comment: yeah. I think this will help. thanks :). Will try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the type of the activities in the Manifest file,
For the Activity, you want to start first, declare its action the manifest file as,

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

and for the activity, you want to start next to first activity, declare its action in mainfest as,

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
```

and for the question you ask about having transparent dialogues, you can define the theme for the dialogue layout as tranparent or you can create your own theme for the dialogue..

Answer (score 0):

You'd be better off using a dialog to achieve this as its not quite how Activites are meant to be used. Look up fragments as well, i haven't used them yet but they might provide an alternative to using a dialog.

Activities tend to replace each other in there entirety so you won't get the previous activity in the background. Hence a dialog or fragment would be a better approach.

You should be able to find examples searching the android tutorials.

Comment: Is it possbile to have transparent dialogues or something, that would look like its overlapping the other?